# How can I fix this missing Derby ClientDriver issue?

Tags: javadb

I am pretty new to [Java DB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Derby), and I'm trying to set up Java DB in NetBeans IDE using this tutorial: *[Working with the Java DB (Derby) Database](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/java-db.html)*

During the step, where it tells to create database, I get such an error:

> An error occurred while creating the database: 
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.Clientdriver

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Which version of Derby / Java DB are you using?

If it is 10.15.1.3, see this response: *[Where is org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver for version 10.15.1.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57216394/where-is-org-apache-derby-jdbc-clientdriver-for-version-10-15-1-3)*

Within NetBeans, there seems to be the same issue with ClientDriver. As a workaround, download and use Derby 10.14.2.0 instead. A NetBeans bug report, Apache [Jira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jira_(software)) [Netbeans-3424](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-3424) has been submitted.

Answer (score 1):

I found it in `lib\derbytools.jar\org\apache\derby\jdbc`.

I copied the entire `jdbc` folder and pasted in `lib\derbyclient.jar\org\apache\derby`

Then it works.