# Connect Derby to Java

Tags: java, derby

I'm trying to connect to a database using Derby in Java (using NetBeans), but I keep getting this error when I try to create a new database:

> An error occurred while crating the database java.lang.ClassNotFoundException;  org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver.

I've tried using Derby 10.16.1.1 and Derby 10.14.2.1.

Comment: Please make sure that derbyclient.jar is in your classpath.

Comment: I don't believe it said *"crating the database"*. This looks like a transcription error (*"[creating](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/create#Verb) the database"*).

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56690250/how-can-i-fix-missing-derby-clientdriver-issue) is an example where it it ***"creating*** *the database"*.

Answer (score 2):

The error message you are seeing suggests that the class `org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver` is not being found by the class loader at runtime. This class is necessary for connecting to a Derby database.

There are few possible causes:

1. The Derby [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) driver is not in the class path of your project or application.
2. The version of JDBC driver JAR file isn’t the correct version for the version of Derby you are using. Please, check versions.

There is a comprehensive [Derby documentation](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.15/getstart/index.html) where you can find more information and step-by-step guides.

---

In order to add `org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver` to your class path, you can do few things, depending on your development environment:

1. If you're using an IDE like [NetBeans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans), you can add the JAR file to the project's build path by IDE UI, for example, the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879903/how-to-add-a-jar-in-netbeans) explains how to do so.
2. If you're building your project with a build tool like [Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) or [Gradle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradle), you can add the JAR file as a dependency in your project's `pom.xml` file or `build.gradle` file. You can read more about that approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396245/add-a-dependency-in-maven) and [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html)
3. If you're running your project from the command line, you can add the JAR file to the classpath by specifying it as a command-line argument when running your project's main class. For example, if the jar file is located in `/lib/derby-jdbc.jar`, the command would be:

   ```
   java -cp /lib/derby-jdbc.jar YourMainClass
   ```